# I would like my posts to pull my custom cropped thumbnail instead of creating its own thumbnail from Featured Image

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

Firstly, I'm not a developer, mostly a website designer and CSS hacker.

I'll try to explain better:

I'm using a grid theme that creates a thumbnail out of the featured image to display as a post teaser. My previous theme would do the same, but would use the custom thumbnail that I created in the Thumbnail Setttings in the Media Library.

I imagine this is a simple change, maybe in the functions.php file?

I looked in the existing posts, but could not find a suitable answer. Feel free to link me to an existing thread discussing this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the Thumbnail size that you set in `Settings -> Media Settings`?

Comment: Can you locate the piece of code responsible for *"creating a thumbnail out of the featured image"* ? This is possible using Firebug and searching inside the theme files.

Comment: @Ahmad M, In essence yes, I would set the thumbnail size to match my theme's grid pattern, then ensure any thumbnails I crop are either made to that size, or at least at that ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is using `the_post_thumbnail()` to display the featured image, adding the following code in `functions.php` file will display the Thumbnail size of the image (as set on Settings -> Media Settings):

```
add_filter('post_thumbnail_size', 'my_thumbnail_size');
function my_thumbnail_size() {
    return 'thumbnail';
}
```

Or you can display the featured image in any width (X) or height (Y) you wish:

```
add_filter('post_thumbnail_size', 'my_thumbnail_size');
function my_thumbnail_size() {
    return array(X,Y);
}
```